# Yii2 multiple language

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on yii2 framework. I want to setup multiple language option for a shopping cart site(english and arabic). I tried some way but didn't got success.

1. create a copy of each table in database.
2. Connect different database for each language
3. add two fields for language in a table.

Which is better? or any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 has a section dedicated to that in the documentation

[Internationalization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html)

Following the steps, you can create the tables of translations and how to use 
`Yii::t()`

Comment: The contents are added from backend.When the user choose a language from frontend is all the contents will be changed to the selected language by using internationalization??

Comment: The output can be managed by `I18n` libraries of  and `Yii: t ()`. 
What it does is store the strings and their respective translations in the database and manages them depending on the value of `\ Yii::$app->language`

Answer (score 1):

I did answer recently another post regarding this, there I proposed kind of a strategy that works in a ver complex architecture I have with a client. Please read that answer, I hope it helps you and other.

There I discuss 3 main components.
 1. Message Translation.
 2. Route Dynamic Translation.
 3. Database content translation.

[Yii2 best practices translating dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787864/yii2-best-practices-translating-dynamic-content/46897791#46897791)

And all that I discuss there is based in the documentation provides on Yii2 [i18n Message translation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html) discused in teh other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution:

Example:

```
tablename = post
```

table has this fields:

```
id
post_title
post_content
language
slug 
...
```

slug -unique string for each post.

```
id  | post_title      | post_content      |slug       |...
1     title_en         content_en          title_slug
2     title_ar         content_ar          title_slug
3     title_fr         content_fr          title_slug
4     title_uz         content_uz          title_slug
```

You may set url like this:

http://example.com/en/post/title_slug

Answer (score 0):

Do a search on packagist.org for lajax/yii2-translatemanager. It can scan your directories as well as client-side javascript code for language strings to translate and includes a TranslateBehavior for handling database content. For database content, you need to use the behavior in the applicable models with columns requiring translation and define the table columns themselves in your config file. It was designed to be used with the advanced template but can be easily adapted with config file changes to be used with the basic template. You can find several video tutorials on youtube about this particular topic.

There are several ways of designing database schemas to handle language translation. You should be able to find examples on packagist.org. Try doing a search for 'Yii2 language translation'.