# Yii2 i18n not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm having trouble into working with i18n in Yii2 advanced template.
Translation is not working!

I have run these commands in yii2 project root directory.

[Official link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html)

```
./yii message/config --languages=de,it,fr  --messagePath=messages i18n.php 
./yii message/extract i18n.php
```

It generate i18n.php under project root directory and de,it,fr directories under message directory.
in de directory I have create new file `app.php` with this content:

```
<?php
return [
    'Home' => 'Home de',
    'Getting Started' => 'Getting Started de',
];
```

In common/config/main.php

```
// set target language to be English
    'language' => 'en-US',

  // set source language to be English
 'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
'components' => [
        'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../').'messages',
                //'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                //'fileMap' => [
                    //'app' =>  realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../').'app.php',
                  //  'app/error' => 'error.php',
                //],
            ],
            ],
        ],
]
```

View:

```
<?= Yii::t('app','Home')?>
<?= Yii::t('app','Getting Started') ?>
```

How I can get it working?

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831288/yii2-translation-does-not-work/32835641#32835641

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set target language in your config:

```
...
'language' => 'ru-RU',
...
```

If `'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',` yii will translate from `en-US` to `ru-RU`.

And config `i18n` component will be:

```
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        'app' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'basePath' => '@app/translation',
            'fileMap' => [
                 'app' => 'app.php',
            ],
        ],
    ],
 ],
```

Directory structure is:

```
- translation
    - ru-RU
        - app.php
```

Example in file `app.php`

```
return [
    'Home' => 'abcxyz',
    'source key' => 'translate to russian',
];
```

Hope it helpful.

Goodluck and have fun!

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: " If 'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US', yii will translate from en-US to ru-RU. "
this part is very important. If you happen to change this to your viewing language, like I did, yii2 won't translate at all!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using advanced template,edit i18n.php

```
'sourcePath' =>__DIR__. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
```

which will create message folder inside common folder.

And in config file

```
'components' => [
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        'app*' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'basePath' => '@common/messages',
            'fileMap' => [
                'app' => 'app.php',
                'app/error' => 'error.php',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
....
]
```

and in view use as you have.Good Luck