# Yii2 i18n translation and redundant source language text

Tags: php, yii, internationalization, yii2, translation

I'm new on the i18n topic and I try to set-up an i18n web-application.
Reading trough different docs and examples, it looks like, all provided possibilities works nearly the same, which means:

On the view side I have an text in source language:

`echo Yii:t('contact','This is a log text about contact informations.');`

In the translation-files (with format for CPhpMessageSource or GNU gettext) or an translation table, **I have to repeat this source-text again** as an anchor, like in my by-DE file for CPhpMessageSource:

```
return array(
    'This is a log text about contact informations.' 
         => 'Des is a langa Text üba Kontakt Infoamadiona.',
);
```

This means, I have to keep the source text redundant (view and very single translation-file), which is not optimal to maintain content.

Of cause I could set an ID/anchor instead of the source text, like:

`echo Yii:t('contact','ContactInfo');`

return array(
    'ContactInfo' 
         => 'Des is a langa Text üba Kontakt Infoamadiona.'
);

But in this case I cannot inject dynamic elements/variables into the text.

**My questions:**

1. Will this an ID/anchor concept (case 2) valid with the Yii2 sourceLanguage mechanism?
2. So, did I understood the concept of i18n Yii-Application design right?
3. Would it be possible do something like this

(sourceLanguage and targetLanguage only once)

```
return array(
    'ContactInfo' => array(
         'en-US' => 'This is a log text about contact informations.',
         'by-DE' => 'Des is a langa Text üba Kontakt Infoamadiona.'
      )
);
```

Comment: Refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831288/yii2-translation-does-not-work/32835641#32835641

Answer (score 1):

[Yii 2] The reason behind the need to repeat the source text in translation is to provide the identifier for this text.
You **can** use some kind of labels instead but then you can not get the default text (not label) when there is no need for translation (target language is the same as source language) **unless** you *force it* in configuration:

```
'components' => [
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'category' => [
                // ...
                'forceTranslation' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Now you can use `\Yii::t('category', 'Label1')` and in messages file you can add:

```
return [
    'Label1' => 'This is expanded text behind the Label1.',
];
```

As for the variables here you can use them without any problems, i.e.:

```
\Yii::t('category', 'Label1', ['aaa' => 1, 'bbb' => 2])
```

and in messages file:

```
return [
    'Label1' => 'Label1 with variables: aaa is {aaa} and bbb is {bbb}.',
];
```

As for the question #3 - this is not possible without some special preparation.

Comment: This mean: using variables in the translated text, not the label/sourceLanguage will work!?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow... What's the difference?

Comment: I though, that I had to pass the parameter place-holder from the view, where the translation-label exists, until the message file. (like: "This is al label-text with parameter: {aaa}"). But in your example I see the parameter place-holder in the message-file only. This is good to know.