# Yii2 default errors internationalization

Tags: yii2, internationalization

On my "messages" folder I have 3 folders ("en", "es" and "fr"). All of them have app.php file where I have placed my translations. But in "es" and "fr" folder I have 2 additional files (yii.php and zii.php) that I used on my first version of Yii 1. This files give me the translations of default error, like:

```
  '{attribute} cannot be blank.' => '{attribute} no puede ser nulo.',
```

Now, in Yii2, I don't know how can I "say" to Yii that this files exists because now , the errors appears on English despite of the language of the webpage is Spanish.

On my web.php config file I have:

```
'i18n' => [
          'translations' => [
              'yii' => [
                  'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                  'basePath' => 'app\messages',
                  'sourceLanguage' => 'es',
                  'fileMap' => [
                      'app' => 'app.php',
                    ],
              ],
          ],
        ],
```

My config.php file of messages folder has the following content:

```
return array(
'sourcePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'messagePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'messages',
'languages'=>array('ar','bg','bs','ca','cs','da','de','el','es','fa_ir','fi','fr','he','hu','id','it','ja','kk','ko_kr','lt','lv','nl','no','pl','pt','pt_br','ro','ru','sk','sr_sr','sr_yu','sv','ta_in','th','tr','uk','vi','zh_cn','zh_tw'),
'fileTypes'=>array('php'),
'overwrite'=>true,
'exclude'=>array(
    '.svn',
    '.gitignore',
    'yiilite.php',
    'yiit.php',
    '/i18n/data',
    '/messages',
    '/vendors',
    '/web/js',
),
```

);

Thanks.

**SOLUTION:**
The problem was with my web.php code, I just remove 'basePath' line and it works now.

Comment: Refer my answer may be helped [Yii2 Translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831288/yii2-translation-does-not-work/32835641#32835641)

Comment: @vishuB I get the following error on step 5: Error: The source path /home/myuser/Proyectos/proj1/config../../../ is not a valid directory.

Comment: check project directory path and try.

Comment: which template use yii2 basic or yii2 advanced ?

Comment: My project directory path is  /home/myuser/Proyectos/proj1, and I had to run the command with php: php yii message/extract config/i18n.php, same with migrations, I dont know why. I'm using basic template I think. @vishuB

Comment: I just see that I have created config.php file on messages path (it was created automatically) with similar content of i18n.php of your post

Comment: try this command `php yii message/extract @app/config/i18n.php`

Comment: same error... (I have edited my post with config.php content)

Comment: your project directory `sourcePath` is invalid. set this `'sourcePath' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,`

Comment: also set `messagePath` like `'messagePath' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'messages',`

Comment: Thanks for your answers @vishuB but still not working..

Comment: what error get ?

Comment: same error with source path: The source path /home/myuser/Proyectos/proj1/config../../../ is not a valid directory.

Comment: means your project directory `sourcePath` is invalid set.

Comment: Its ok now, I'm gonna edit my post with the solution. However, thanks @vishuB for your attention.

Comment: please upvote when my [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831288/yii2-translation-does-not-work/32835641#32835641) answer is usefull

Comment: I can't upvote, low reputation yet.